# Dependency Injection to Custom Formatter with Multiple Class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I created one custom formatter to give output as pdf. Please refer more details in the following thread:

[Dependency Injection to CustomFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43512810/dependency-injection-to-customformatter)

It is working fine as per the answer. But now i have 2 reports like below;

```
public interface IPdfFactory {
    MemoryStream Create(object model);
}

public class BillReport: IPdfFactory {
    private readonly IBusinessLogic _logic;

    public PdfFactory(IBusinessLogic logic) {
        this._logic = logic;
    }

    public MemoryStream Create(object model) {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        //...Pdf generation code

        //call data update
        _logic.update(model);

        return stream;
    }
}

public class PurchaseReport: IPdfFactory {
    private readonly IBusinessLogic _logic;

    public PdfFactory(IBusinessLogic logic) {
        this._logic = logic;
    }

    public MemoryStream Create(object model) {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        //...Pdf generation code

        //call data update
        _logic.update(model);

        return stream;
    }
}
```

Here how can i specify in dependency injection. I read about context binding and it think it resolved the issue.

I just added injection like the below;

```
        kernel.Bind<IPdfFactory>().To<BillReport>().When(request => request.Target.Member.Name.StartsWith("Bill"));
        kernel.Bind<IPdfFactory>().To<PurchaseReport>().When(request => request.Target.Member.Name.StartsWith("Purchase"));
        kernel.Bind<PdfMediaTypeFormatter>().ToSelf();
```

In the WebApi config,

```
        var formatter = (PdfMediaTypeFormatter)config.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(PdfMediaTypeFormatter));
        config.Formatters.Add(formatter);
```

When run, i always got null in formatter. Please help me to find the error

***Update:***

I used ninject.extensions.factory. I changed my code like below;

```
public interface IPdfFactory
{
    IReport GetPurchaseReport();
    IReport GetBillReport();
}
public interface IReport
{
    Task<MemoryStream> Create(object model);
}
```

Now my BillReport and PurchaseReport implements IReport interface. Also the Pdfmapper class have IReport interface only

The ninject cofiguration code like below;

```
    kernel.Bind<IReport>().To<PurchaseReport>().Named("PurchaseReport");
    kernel.Bind<IReport>().To<BillReport>().Named("BillReport");
    kernel.Bind<IPdfFactory>().ToFactory();
    kernel.Bind<PdfMediaTypeFormatter>().ToSelf();
```

In the config, custom formatter adding area again i got formatter as null

```
    var formatter = (PdfMediaTypeFormatter)config.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(PdfMediaTypeFormatter));
    config.Formatters.Add(formatter);
```

***New update:***

My ninject configuration:

```
kernel.Bind<IReport>().To<PurchaseReport>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IReport>().To<BillReport>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<IPdfFactory>().To<PdfFactory>().InRequestScope();
            kernel.Bind<PdfMediaTypeFormatter>().ToSelf();
```

In webapi config:

```
    var formatter = (PdfMediaTypeFormatter)config.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(PdfMediaTypeFormatter));
    config.Formatters.Add(formatter);
```

now also formatter is null . anything missed?

Comment: Please make this a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]) without just relying on linking to your old question.

Comment: Also please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Comment: sure thanks for the notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update report interface to be able identify which models it can handle

```
public interface IReport {
    bool CanHandle(object model);
    Task<MemoryStream> Create(object model);
}
```

Assuming some example models like this.

```
class BillModel : IPdf {
    //...
}

class PurchaseModel : IPdf {
    //...
}
```

the report implementations would have some thing similar to the logic in the formatter.

```
public class BillReport : IReport {
    Func<Type, bool> typeisIPdf = (type) => typeof(BillModel).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    Func<Type, bool> typeisIPdfCollection = (type) => typeof(IEnumerable<BillModel>).
    IsAssignableFrom(type);

    private readonly IBusinessLogic _logic;

    public BillReport(IBusinessLogic logic) {
        this._logic = logic;
    }

    public bool CanHandle(object model) {
        if (model == null) return false;
        var type = model.GetType();
        return typeisIPdf(type) || typeisIPdfCollection(type);
    }

    public Task<MemoryStream> Create(object model) {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        if (CanHandle(model.GetType())) {
            //...Pdf generation code
            //call data update
            _logic.update(model);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(stream);
    }

}

public class PurchaseReport : IReport {
    Func<Type, bool> typeisIPdf = (type) => typeof(PurchaseModel).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    Func<Type, bool> typeisIPdfCollection = (type) => typeof(IEnumerable<PurchaseModel>).
    IsAssignableFrom(type);
    private readonly IBusinessLogic _logic;

    public PurchaseReport(IBusinessLogic logic) {
        this._logic = logic;
    }

    public bool CanHandle(object model) {
        if (model == null) return false;
        var type = model.GetType();
        return typeisIPdf(type) || typeisIPdfCollection(type);
    }

    public Task<MemoryStream> Create(object model) {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        if (CanHandle(model.GetType())) {
            //...Pdf generation code
            //call data update
            _logic.update(model);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(stream);
    }
}
```

The factory would now just need to be aware of all the implementations of `IReport`. It would then get the report that can handle the provided model and perform desired function

```
public class PdfFactory : IPdfFactory {
    private IEnumerable<IReport> reports;
    public PdfFactory(IReport[] reports) {
        this.reports = reports;
    }

    public Task<MemoryStream> Create(object model) {
        var report = reports.FirstOrDefault(r => r.CanHandle(model));
        if (report != null) {
            return report.Create(model);
        }
        return Task.FromResult<MemoryStream>(null);
    }
}
```

The advantage of using this abstraction approach is that you do not even have to update the formatter and all changes are being made on the other dependencies and implementation concerns.

Make sure to register all the `IReport` implementations so that they will be passed to the `IPdfFactory` when resolved.

Referring to [Multi injection](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection) documentation

```
kernel.Bind<IReport>().To<PurchaseReport>();
kernel.Bind<IReport>().To<BillReport>();
kernel.Bind<IPdfFactory>().To<PdfFactory>();
kernel.Bind<PdfMediaTypeFormatter>().ToSelf();
```

Comment: I think there's some room for improvement: Very similar code in `typeisIPdf`, `typeisIPdfCollection`, `CanHandle` and `Create`.
The mapping of an unspecific type `object` to a specific type (`Bill`, `Purchase`...) is repeated again and again.